# My sandboxed app was running fine in 10.8 but in 10.9 it seems that user defaults .plist is not saved at all

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults, sandbox, osx-mavericks

Sandboxed app was running fine in 10.8 but in 10.9 it seems that user defaults. plist is not saved at all. The location of plist is:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.example.myapp/Data/Library/Preferences/com.example.myapp.plist
```

and if I delete it, it will not be created again. In 10.8 this was working.

Has anyone seen this before or can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Rather than deleting the files via the filesystem, use 'defaults delete', NSUserDefaults, or CFPreferences to remove the data. If you must use the filesystem, an unsupported workaround that's less time consuming than rebooting is to run 'killall -SIGTERM cfprefsd'. Note that deleting preferences files manually has never actually worked completely reliably, or been supported.

Comment: Thanks Catfish_Man. This is the workaround and explanation for this. Apparently cfprefsd changed cache behaviour and the solution for a delete container is to either 1)Use 'defaults delete' to delete preferences
2) Run 'killall -SIGTERM cfprefsd' after deleting a container
3) Log out or reboot after deleting a container...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved with a reboot, well short of.
Preferences are saved correctly and it works fine until I delete again the app container folder. Then a reboot is required again to fix this.

Comment: It took me 2 hours until I found this. Rebooting helps. I would say this is a bug in Sandboxing

Comment: Great that I finally found this post. I just wasted two days trying to figure out why my code to store security scope bookmarks in the preferences suddenly had broken. A reboot indeed helped... (Yes, I guess I had at some point while iterating building a new version of the app (very complex, non-Xcode build mechanism), packaging, re-installing it using sudo installer etc, manually removed the plist file, among with the rest of the container. Which apparently is a bad move.)

Answer (score 7):

My work-around for this problem is to kill the 'cfprefsd' daemon processes after making a change to the .plist file:

> ps auwx | grep cfprefsd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -2

The daemons will be restarted after the next access of the .plist file and will then have the new value for the key that was changed.

It is unfortunate that this work-around is necessary but at least it works reliably.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very issue last night (I am still developing my app).  I fixed it by deleting the app container folder (moving the whole `~/Library/Containers/com.domain.appname` to trash in Finder) and re-running the app.

I rebooted first as I saw that there was some sort of `LSShared` file, related to my app, that wouldn't be emptied from the trash before the reboot.

I can only imagine it's an intermittent bug in Mavericks (GM seed).

**EDIT** The comment about a bug may not be true; it looks like `.plist` files are "on their way out" according to this [Apple Developer Forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/873209#873209).  However at the end of the day my app (and the OPs) stopped working, so it isn't working reliably.

Comment: In my case, after I delete the container folder it is indeed re-created on first run from xcode. Yet any change in preferences is not saved. Like NSUserDefaults is not synchronized at all, even if I call it my self

Comment: @xarp Ah, I will recheck tonight, however I did test running, changing preferences, closing and restarting and all worked well.  I will run a more thorough test.

Comment: The forum thread was close, but a little confused on some details. I replied to it with more accurate information.